# Связать две переменные на C#

Tags: c#, binding

Ещё не совсем въехал в Binding. Требуется создать привязку двух произвольных переменных, то есть сделать так, чтобы изменение одной из них влекло за собой изменение и другой, в обе стороны. Реально это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы говорите об автоматической связи произвольных *переменных* — такого сделать нельзя. Изменение переменной нельзя «перехватить».

Вы можете, однако, легко синхронизировать свойства *изнутри* самих свойств. Например:

```
private int a;
public int A
{
    get { return a; }
    set { if (value != a) { a = value; B = value; } }
}

private int b;
public int B
{
    get { return b; }
    set { if (value != b) { b = value; A = value; } }
}
```

Здесь, однако, переменные в коде сильно связаны: код, ответственный за `A` должен знать о `B` (и наоборот).

Для того, чтобы развязать их, можно, например воспользоваться механизмом событий: изменение одной переменной посылает событие, по приходу которого можно обновить и другую переменную. В C# для таких целей чаще всего используется интерфейс [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx), который позволяет *подписаться* на изменения свойства (и *отписаться*, тоже), и менять значение другой переменной в соответствии:

```
class С : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int a;
    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set
        {
            if (a == value)
                return;
            a = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("A");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

// где-то в другом классе

c.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => this.B = c.A;
```

---

Теперь насчёт `Binding`. `Binding` — часть фреймворка WPF, и употребляется для автоматической связи между двумя свойствами. Свойство-источник может быть обыкновенным, или быть реализованным как [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx), целевое свойство обязано быть dependency property.

Если свойство-источник поддерживает интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` или является dependency property, `Binding` может подписаться на изменения и узнавать о них, и обновлять целевое свойство. В противном случае `Binding` прочитает значение из него только один раз при создании, автоматического обновления не будет.

Для того, чтобы работал `TwoWay`-`Binding`, необходимо, чтобы оба связываемых свойства являлись dependency property.

Заметьте, что dependency property обладают потоковой привязкой: к ним можно обращаться только из одного потока. Возможно, это не то, что вам нужно, в этом случае логику привязки придётся писать вручную через `INotifyPropertyChanged`.